# Move a table next to an image

Tags: html, css

This is how my webpage looks:

```
-------------
-------------   
 Image here     
-------------
-------------
Table1 here
Table2 here
Table3 here
```

I was hoping to make it look like this:

```
-------------
-------------   
 Image here     Table1 here
-------------
-------------
Table2 here     Table3 here
```

HTML:

```
   <img class="image" src="somesrc"> 
   <table id="table-1">
       <tbody>
         <tr class="row-1">
           <td class="column-1">something</td><td class="column-2">something</td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="row-2">
           <td class="column-1">something</td><td class="column-2">something</td>
        </tr>
The same for the other 2 tables but with different ID
```

CSS:

```
.image {
 height: auto;
 width: 250px;
}

#table-1, #table-2, #table-3 {
    width: 40%;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#table-1 .column-1, #table-2 .column-1, #table-3 .column-1 {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #fff;
    width: 40%;
}
```

I have no idea how to move table1 to the desired position. Each table has a heading above it too.

Comment: There's no images in your HTML.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I added the HTML and css of the image

Comment: Did you plan on closing the table? `</tbody></table>`

Comment: use div to separate img and table

Comment: You should _float_ the images and tables or use _flexbox_. Using a grid would also be helpful.

Comment: They are closed @zer00ne but I forgot to add them to the above code

Comment: When I float the tables, the headings dont move

Comment: Stew, then you need to **1)** do what @Paulie_D said above and provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (which you have not) and **2)** group the header and table inside of another element and float that element instead of the table.

Comment: Thank you for the tips Hungerstar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
    <div class="image">
   <img src="somesrc"> 
   </div>
   <table id="table-1">
       <tbody>
         <tr class="row-1">
           <td class="column-1">something</td><td class="column-2">something</td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="row-2">
           <td class="column-1">something</td><td class="column-2">something</td>
        </tr>
```

CSS:

```
.image {
 height: auto;
 width: 250px;
 float:right;
}

#table-1, #table-2, #table-3 {
    width: 40%;
    font-weight: bold;

}

#table-1 .column-1, #table-2 .column-1, #table-3 .column-1 {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #fff;
    width: 40%;
    float:left;
}
```

I added a div with the class image and deleted the class in `<img>` then i just added a `float:right` to that div. and a `float:left` to the table. Check the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/amsuh474/2/

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to float your elements. Sample below.

```css
table {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 10px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.image {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 40%;
}
.pull-left {
  float: left;
}
.clearfix {
  clear: both;  
}
```

```html
<div class="image pull-left">IMAGE</div>
<table class="pull-left">
  <tr>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<table class="pull-left">
  <tr>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="pull-left">
  <tr>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I know it's just a demo but...personally not a fan of using elements to clear floats, that's so early 2000s. May I suggest a [proper clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure how the visual spacing between the image and the table should be vs the two tables below but I'm going to give you an example using a grid to layout page elements. You can roll your own or use a grid from any number of CSS frameworks like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid), [Skeleton](http://getskeleton.com/#grid), [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/grid.html) etc.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.row {
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-right: -10px;
  overflow: hidden; /* cheap clearfix - should use: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/ */
}
[class^="col-"] {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.col-half {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-half">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x175/ffcc00/?text=example">
  </div>

  <div class="col-half">

    <h2>Table 1</h2>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>

</div>

<div class="row">

  <div class="col-half">

    <h2>Table 2</h2>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>

  <div class="col-half">

    <h2>Table 3</h2>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the image and a table in an element (in the example it's `<section>`) and the remaining 2 tables in another block element(`section>`). Then wrap everything in another element (`<main>`). Apply [`display: table-*` CSS properties](http://colintoh.com/blog/display-table-anti-hero) to each as the Snippet demonstrates.

```css
#main {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
section {
  display: table-row;
}
figure,
table {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  border: 2px dashed red;
}
td {
  width: 25%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: calc(50% - 25vh);
}
figcaption {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<main id='main'>
  <section>
    <figure>
      <figcaption>IMAGE</figcaption>
      <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png'>
    </figure>
    <table>
      <caption>TABLE1</caption>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>TD</td>
          <td>TD</td>
          <td>TD</td>
          <td>Tables will stretch with their content accordingly.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD</td>
          <td>This content is added just to fill out the rest of the dead space.</td>
          <td>TD</td>
          <td>TD</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>This content is added just to fill out the rest of the dead space.</td>
          <td>TD</td>
          <td>TD</td>
          <td>TD</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </section>
  <section>
    <table>
      <caption>TABLE2</caption>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>TD</td>
          <td>TD</td>
          <td>TD</td>
          <td>This content is added just to fill out the rest of the dead space.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD</td>
          <td>The maximum width of each table is 50% of viewport</td>
          <td>TD</td>
          <td>TD</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>This content is added just to fill out the rest of the dead space.</td>
          <td>TD</td>
          <td>TD</td>
          <td>TD</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table>
      <caption>TABLE3</caption>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>TD</td>
          <td>TD</td>
          <td>TD</td>
          <td>This content is added just to fill out the rest of the dead space.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD</td>
          <td>This content is added just to fill out the rest of the dead space.</td>
          <td>TD</td>
          <td>TD</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD</td>
          <td>TD</td>
          <td>TD</td>
          <td>This content is added just to fill out the rest of the dead space.</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </section>
</main>
```